Promoting IG pages which contain music on reels
Assalamu Aleykum,recently i started to repost sport cars (without music) on my Instagram page,but i have some doubts about the credit that i give to people whom i take the reels, is that on their pages they have music on their content so i would like to know if i commiting a sin on promoting their pages because they post sport cars like me but the difference they using music in some of their contents,if someone can answer thx very much
